# setup.py puts copy of generated shared library in root site-packages directory

Tags: python, distutils

Using python2.7, I have the following snippet for setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name='The Foo Package',
  packages=['foo'],
  ext_package='foo',
  ext_modules = [Extension("my_extension",
                           ["foo/my_extension.c"],
                           language='c',
                           include_dirs=['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'])]
 )
```

The directory structure is:

```
root
| setup.py
| foo\
    | some_python_module.py
    | my_extension.c
```

What I *expect* to happen is that `my_extension.so` ends up in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo/` together with the `.pyc` files and so on, but what happens instead is that it ends up there *and* also directly in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

I tried both the `ext_package='foo'` kwarg to `setup` and also throwing that out and using `foo.my_extension` in the constructor of `Extension`, but get the same effect in both cases.

NOTE: The `.c` file was generated with `cython`, not sure if/how that matters.

Comment: Quick check: are you sure the one in `site-packages` isn't left over from earlier work?

Comment: Turns out it kinda was :/ I'm stupid.